# How does 'self' in python prevent issues with calling functions before they are declared?

Tags: python

Here is a minimal example code where 'self' is utilized

```
class Solution2:
    def inorderTraversal(self, a):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        b = self.helper(a)
        return b

    def helper(self, a):
        return a

sol2 = Solution2()

e = sol2.inorderTraversal(7)
print(e)

#output
>7
```

And here is a minimal example code where self is not utilized

```
class Solution:
    def inorderTraversal(self, a):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        b = helper(a)
        return b

    def helper( a):
        return a

sol = Solution()

d = sol.inorderTraversal(7)
print(d)
```

Which gives the error

```
NameError: name 'helper' is not defined
```

I know that 'self' is used in python to seperate instances of objects with unique initilizers, but some how in this case, it is being used to prevent an error that comes from calling a function/method before it is declared.

Comment: change `helper(a)` to `Solution.helper(a)` and add `@staticmethod` over `def helper(...)`

Comment: That worked. I would like to know how this prevented the error. I'm guessing the self or class name elicited the to check the entire class. So does 'self' and the class name mean the same thing in this instance? Are they interchangable? Is 'self' and the class that the function belongs two are interchangeable in all instances in python?

Comment: `helper()` is defined within the `class` namespace. To call it you need to reference the class or an instance thereof first. If you want to use it independent of an instance, decorate it either with `@staticmethod` or `@classmethod`. It's kind of analogous to importing a module (and its namespace) and referencing the module before calling a function within the module.

Comment: I see. So whenever I see 'self' in python, I can interchange it with the name of the class it belongs to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you define a method in a class body, the method could be

- instance method (it needs `self` as first argument)
- static method (declared with `@staticmethod` decorator)
- class method (declared with `@classmethod` decorator)

in your case the `helper()` method does not match one of those categories. the problem is not the order of declaration but the syntax itself